# Removing a slice of keys within a Map with time complexity better than O(n^2) in Go

Tags: go

Basic approach to delete multiple keys from an array of Maps in **Go**, would be by using nested loops, that is with a parent loop for iterating over array of Maps and an inner loop of *slice* of Keys to be deleted. Is there a way to do this without using nested loops. Just trying to figure out a way to get better time complexity that O(n^2).

Comment: Why loop on the map?

Comment: Even with two loops, time complexity would be O(n*m), which is quite different from O(n^2) (which of the two sizes is n?)

Comment: Sorry, just corrected the question @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yes but taking worse case if both are of size **n**, then I was checking if there is a way to lower the time complexity.

Comment: With a collection of maps, it's impossible to get time complexity better than O(n*m). Naturally, excluding edge cases in which, say, all maps are references to the same one object in memory and you only have to touch one reference.

Comment: Maybe you should detail your problem more and there is a structural/architectural problem in it?

Comment: You might be able to get a better wall clock time by parallelising operations to do more than one map in your array at once

Comment: You can write it without nested loops: `for i := 0; i < nmaps * nkeys; i++ { delete(maps[i / nkeys], keys[i % nkeys]) }`. This however does not go faster than nested loops, it goes slower.

Answer (score 1):

> Removing a slice of keys within a Map with time complexity better than
> O(n^2) in Go

---

What is n? Why is time complexity O(n^2)?

---

Consider real code and real cases:

```
package main

func mapsDeleteUniqueKeys(maps []map[string]int, keys []string) {
    // iterations = len(keys) × len(maps)
    for _, k := range keys {
        for _, m := range maps {
            delete(m, k)
        }
    }
}

func mapsDeleteDuplicateKeys(maps []map[string]int, keys []string) {
    // iterations = len(keys) + (len(unique) × len(maps))
    unique := make(map[string]struct{}, len(keys))
    for _, k := range keys {
        unique[k] = struct{}{}
    }
    for k := range unique {
        for _, m := range maps {
            delete(m, k)
        }
    }
}

func main() {}
```

---

What is the growth function for the number of keys? What is the growth function for the number of maps? What is the growth function for the number of keys times the number of maps?

Is the time spent on each iteration significant?

In your case: What do the keys represent? In your case: What do the maps represent?

What worst-case time complexity do you expect to encounter in the real world?

What Go benchmarks have you run? What were the results?

---

Time complexity appears to be O(len(keys) × len(maps)), or O(k × m),.
In practice len(maps), the number of maps, is likely small relative to len(keys), the number of keys. The number of maps may also be constant. Therefore, the time complexity is likely near O(len(keys)) or O(n).